# I want to add an Alert Dialog in my Catch block in flutter

Tags: flutter

This Code is for FireBase SignUp

```
onPressed: () async {
    if (_emailController.text.isEmpty || _passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
        throw _showDialog2(context);
    }
    FirebaseUser user;
    if (user == null) {
        try {
            user = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
            _showDialog(context);
            await user.sendEmailVerification();
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
            switch (e.code) {
                case "ERROR_EMAIL_AlREADY_IN_USE":
                  setState(() {
                      errorMsg = "This email is already in use.";
                  });
                  _showDialog1(context);
            }
            print(e.message);
        }
    }
},

Future<Void> _showDialog1(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Alert'),
          content: const Text('User Already Exists'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Ok'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The Dialog Box is not working and User using the won't know what is happening if he tries to signup and it doesn't show any alert.

```
V/FA      (23130): Recording user engagement, ms: 67474
V/FA      (23130): Connecting to remote service
V/FA      (23130): Activity paused, time: 479832386
D/FA      (23130): Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=67474, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=8428444267785459928}]
V/FA      (23130): Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA      (23130): Connected to remote service
V/FA      (23130): Processing queued up service tasks: 2
V/FA      (23130): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
V/FA      (23130): Connecting to remote service
V/FA      (23130): Activity resumed, time: 480570394
W/1.gpu   (23130): type=1400 audit(0.0:73052): avc: denied { search } for name="ctx" dev="debugfs" ino=15090 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c153,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
D/FA      (23130): Connected to remote service
V/FA      (23130): Processing queued up service tasks: 1
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(23130): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@5aa370
W/DynamiteModule(23130): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth(23130): [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth(23130): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
I/flutter (23130): The email address is already in use by another account.
V/FA      (23130): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(23130): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@5aa370
I/flutter (23130): The email address is already in use by another account
```

Does Catch in Flutter support the alert dialog or I have to try some other method for this?
V/FA      (23130): Recording user engagement, ms: 67474
V/FA      (23130): Connecting to remote service
V/FA      (23130): Activity paused, time: 479832386
D/FA      (23130): Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=67474, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=8428444267785459928}]
V/FA      (23130): Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA      (23130): Connected to remote service
V/FA      (23130): Processing queued up service tasks: 2
V/FA      (23130): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
V/FA      (23130): Connecting to remote service
V/FA      (23130): Activity resumed, time: 48057039

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change `Future<Void>` to `Future<void>` because you need to use lowercase void, otherwise sometimes you can error like `'Future<void>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Void>'`

Now, I'm tried your code and it works, are you sure `e.code` is `ERROR_EMAIL_AlREADY_IN_USE` ?

For example all characters uppercase except 'l' inside of ALREADY word.

Also, i suggested `error constants class` to you for like this situations.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your code as below

```
switch (e.code) {
                        case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                          setState(() {
                            errorMsg = "This email is already in use.";
                          });
                          _showDialog1(context);

                      }
```

you cannot throw a dialog. It is a widget you have to render it on screen. so just call your alertdialog.

you have to use **Future<void>** instead of Future<Void>.

Other firebase exceptions you can use are:

```
- EMAIL_EXISTS
- OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED
- TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER
- EMAIL_NOT_FOUND
- INVALID_PASSWORD
- USER_DISABLED
```

Comment: it's not showing the alert even after removing throw. Please suggest any alternative solution

Comment: Please add your _showDialog1() method. Also, add a print log in the switch case to check whether it is targeting platformException or not.

Comment: Please Check I have added the Dialog and log

Answer (score 0):

```
onPressed: () async {
              if (_emailController.text.isEmpty ||
                  _passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
                _showDialog2(context);
              }
              FirebaseUser user;
              if (user == null) {
                try {
                  user = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: email, password: password);
                  _showDialog(context);
                  await user.sendEmailVerification();
                } catch (e) {
                  _showDialog1(context);
                }
              }
            },
```